# Error when plotting in R

Tags: r, csv, plot

Ok, apologies for a real newbie question.

I'm just trying to plot two variables, one which is directly in my csv file and the other which is simply a division of two columns. See code below.

However when I try to do this, R tells me it can't find one of the columns in my csv file. It's clearly shown in the header summary.
What am I doing wrong here?!

```
> defor=read.csv("C:\\*ommitted*\\logit_data.csv")
> head(defor)
   Time Deforested    Total
    1    3        167 12270.15
    2    6        431 12270.15
    3    9        629 12270.15
    4   11        974 12270.15
    5   13       1611 12270.15
    6   15       2279 12270.15
> summary(defor)
  Time         Deforested       Total      
  Min.   : 3.00   Min.   : 167   Min.   :12270  
  1st Qu.: 7.50   1st Qu.: 530   1st Qu.:12270  
  Median :11.00   Median : 974   Median :12270  
  Mean   :10.43   Mean   :1248   Mean   :12270  
  3rd Qu.:14.00   3rd Qu.:1945   3rd Qu.:12270  
  Max.   :16.00   Max.   :2642   Max.   :12270  
> plot(Deforested/Total ~ Time)
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Deforested' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line use

```
plot((defor$Deforested/defor$Total), defor$Time)
```

instead! Without it, R does not know what data frame to plot from. Other plotting methods like `boxplot` support the `~` syntax, but plot itself is just `plot(x,y)`

Answer (score 1):

or you can use with

`with(defor, plot(Deforested/Total~ Time))`

Comment: Nice solution! I didn't know about that syntax before!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Will look into how this works.

Answer (score 1):

or else you can use `?attach` to add the r-object in the search path..so that you dont have to use `object$Column_name` to call it. simply by `Column_name` it will work.

But this is not a recommended approach for data intensive programs.